# Cannot properly view third person anymore

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When I am playing Skyrim, I typically use the third person view.  It is just easier for me to see what is going on.  However, lately when I try to switch to third person, all I get is a zoomed in version with the camera right over my character's right shoulder.  If I draw my weapon, it will zoom out, but zooms back in when I put my weapons away.  I am playing on PS3.  Did I click something by accident?

Comment: I noticed there were certain times when I was unable to change the zoom level in 3rd person. No idea why, but normally if you hold down the button that enters third person, you can use the other controller to zoom in/out.. See if that fixes it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem on Xbox 360 a while back. It is caused by the forced jump to third person when you use werewolf form, typically.

As [James](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/8581/james) said, to fix it, I held the change view button down, and used the camera button to zoom out. Looks like for PS3, that's hold the right stick down, and move the left up and down. :)

Comment: Thanks, looks like that was it.  except now my brightness/contrast is off and all my items are black.  starting to think skyrim wants a break.